# How to deal with two groups of prerequisites, one which must be run before the other?

Tags: testing, makefile

I often find myself in a situation where I want some prerequisites performed, but then I don't care about the order of the other tasks.  This often comes up in testing, where I want to compile the core programs/libraries, but then I'd like to be able to let make handle the test scheduling.

**What is the most appropriate idiom for dealing with multiple groups of prerequisites, one group which must be run before the other?**

The approaches that I've come up with so far are (in the following examples, $(TESTS) are the targets to run the tests, and $(OBJS) are the target to build the objects):

```
test: $(OBJS)
    make $(TESTS)
```

or

```
$(TESTS): $(OBJS)

test: $(TESTS)
```

Comment: The latter avoids an additional invocation of `make` and should probably be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ned says, all things being equal it's best to avoid recursive invocations of make (and when you do, obviously, you should always use `$(MAKE)` and never use `make` to invoke it).

However, sometimes things are not equal and it can significantly less work, and more robust, to invoke make recursively.  If that's the case, *especially* in "stand alone" things like tests where they don't output results that are needed by other rules, then you shouldn't be shy about using recursion.  Recursion has a bad rap, due to the "Recursive make considered harmful" paper which is quite good, but just like `goto` (which I still use in very specific situations as well and can definitely make your code cleaner and clearer when used thoughtfully) sometimes it's the best option.